# Reference-counted smart pointer in C

Tags: c, memory-management, pointers, gcc

## About

I've been experimenting with gcc's `__cleanup__` attribute, and thought it'd be a great fit for a memory-safe smart pointer for C.

This is the implementation. It requires you to use either the helper macros `SHARED_PTR_VAR_*` or declare a variable as `shared_ptr_t __attribute__((__cleanup__(cleanup_shared_ptr))) var={0};`, and since it relies on gcc's extensions, it obviously requires a compiler that supports them.

The reference counting is thread-safe, but the pointer access itself is not synchronized.

### shared_ptr.h

```
#pragma once

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "util.h"

typedef struct shared_ptr_cntrl {
    void * data;
    void (*cleanup)(void*);
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    int64_t count;
    int64_t cntrl_count;
} shared_ptr_cntrl_t;

typedef struct shared_ptr {
    shared_ptr_cntrl_t * cntrl;
} shared_ptr_t;

shared_ptr_t create_shared_ptr(void ** data,void (*cleanup)(void*));

void cleanup_shared_ptr(shared_ptr_t *);

shared_ptr_t copy_shared_ptr(shared_ptr_t *);

static inline shared_ptr_t move_shared_ptr(shared_ptr_t * p){
    shared_ptr_t tmp={p->cntrl};
    p->cntrl=NULL;
    return tmp;
}

static inline void * get_shared_ptr_ptr(shared_ptr_t * p){
    return (p->cntrl)?p->cntrl->data:NULL;
}

#define SHARED_PTR_FROM(type,cleanup,expr) ({\
    type * v=calloc(1,sizeof(type));\
    if(!v) err_exit("\n\nOUT OF MEMORY\n\n");\
    *v=expr;\
    create_shared_ptr((void**)&v,(void(*)(void*))cleanup);\
})

#define SHARED_PTR_FROM_E(cleanup,expr) SHARED_PTR_FROM(__typeof__((expr)),cleanup,expr)

#define SHARED_PTR_VAR_FROM_E(name,cleanup,expr) CLEANUP_VAR_E(cleanup_shared_ptr,name,SHARED_PTR_FROM_E(cleanup,expr))

#define SHARED_PTR_VAR_E(name,expr) CLEANUP_VAR_E(cleanup_shared_ptr,name,expr)

#define SHARED_PTR_VAR_FROM(type,name,cleanup,expr) CLEANUP_VAR_E(cleanup_shared_ptr,name,SHARED_PTR_FROM(type,cleanup,expr));
```

### util.h

```
#define CLEANUP(cleanup) __attribute__((__cleanup__(cleanup)))
#define CLEANUP_VAR(type,cleanup,name) type __attribute__((__cleanup__(cleanup))) name
#define CLEANUP_VAR_E(cleanup,name,expr) CLEANUP_VAR(__typeof__(expr),cleanup,name) = (expr) ;

__attribute__((format(printf,1,2)))
__attribute__((__noreturn__)) void err_exit(const char * fmt,...);
```

### shared_ptr.c

```
#include "shared_ptr.h"

shared_ptr_t create_shared_ptr(void ** data,void (*cleanup)(void*)){
    if(!*data){
        return (shared_ptr_t){NULL};//avoid allocation for NULL pointers
    }
    shared_ptr_cntrl_t * cntrl=calloc(1,sizeof(shared_ptr_cntrl_t));
    cntrl->data=*data;
    *data=NULL;
    cntrl->cleanup=cleanup;
    cntrl->count=1;
    cntrl->cntrl_count=1;
    if(pthread_mutex_init(&cntrl->mutex,NULL)){
        err_exit("Failed to create mutex for shared_ptr");
    }
    return (shared_ptr_t){cntrl};
}

void cleanup_shared_ptr(shared_ptr_t * p){
    if(p->cntrl){
        if(pthread_mutex_lock(&p->cntrl->mutex)){
            err_exit("Failed to lock mutex for shared_ptr");
        }
        p->cntrl->count--;
        p->cntrl->cntrl_count--;
        if(p->cntrl->count==0){
            if(p->cntrl->cleanup){
                p->cntrl->cleanup(p->cntrl->data);
            }
            free(p->cntrl->data);
            p->cntrl->data=NULL;
            if(p->cntrl->cntrl_count==0){
                pthread_mutex_t m=p->cntrl->mutex;
                free(p->cntrl);
                p->cntrl=NULL;
                if(pthread_mutex_unlock(&m)){
                    err_exit("Failed to unlock mutex for shared_ptr");
                }
                if(pthread_mutex_destroy(&m)){
                    err_exit("Failed to destroy mutex for shared_ptr");
                }
                return;
            }
        }
        if(pthread_mutex_unlock(&p->cntrl->mutex)){
            err_exit("Failed to unlock mutex for shared_ptr");
        }
    }
}

shared_ptr_t copy_shared_ptr(shared_ptr_t * p){
    if(p->cntrl){
        if(pthread_mutex_lock(&p->cntrl->mutex)){
            err_exit("Failed to lock mutex for shared_ptr");
        }
        p->cntrl->count++;
        p->cntrl->cntrl_count++;
        if(pthread_mutex_unlock(&p->cntrl->mutex)){
            err_exit("Failed to unlock mutex for shared_ptr");
        }
    }
    return (shared_ptr_t){p->cntrl};
}
```

### util.c

```
#include "util.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void err_exit(const char * fmt,...){
    va_list arg;
    va_start(arg,fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr,fmt,arg);
    va_end(arg);
    exit(1);
}
```

## Example Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "shared_ptr.h"

static void example_destruct(volatile int * p){
    printf("int destruct %d\n",*p);
}

int main(){
    SHARED_PTR_VAR_FROM(volatile int,example_ptr,example_destruct,20);
    
    SHARED_PTR_VAR_E(example_ptr_2,copy_shared_ptr(&example_ptr));
    
    printf("%d\n",*(volatile int*)get_shared_ptr_ptr(&example_ptr_2));
    
    SHARED_PTR_VAR_E(example_ptr_3,move_shared_ptr(&example_ptr_2));
    
    (*(volatile int*)get_shared_ptr_ptr(&example_ptr_3))=23;
    
    {
        SHARED_PTR_VAR_E(example_ptr_4,copy_shared_ptr(&example_ptr));
        SHARED_PTR_VAR_E(example_ptr_5,copy_shared_ptr(&example_ptr));
        SHARED_PTR_VAR_E(example_ptr_6,copy_shared_ptr(&example_ptr));
        SHARED_PTR_VAR_E(example_ptr_7,copy_shared_ptr(&example_ptr));
        SHARED_PTR_VAR_E(example_ptr_8,copy_shared_ptr(&example_ptr));
    }
    
    printf("%d\n",*(volatile int*)get_shared_ptr_ptr(&example_ptr));
    
    (*(volatile int*)get_shared_ptr_ptr(&example_ptr_3))=40;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tolerate `NULL` during clean-up**

As `free(NULL)` is OK, consider a `NULL` test for clean-up

```
void cleanup_shared_ptr(shared_ptr_t * p){
  if (p) {
    ....
  }
}
```

**Lack of documentation**

*.h files deserve some overall comments.  Consider users may not want to wade through the .c file code to deduce functionality.

**Fixed width**

I see no compelling reasons for `int64_t` here.  Consider `int`.  If concerned that `int` is insufficient, go for `intmax_t` or `long long`.

```
// int64_t count, cntrl_count;
int count, cntrl_count;
```

**Missing guard**

`util.h` lacks a `#pragma once` or the like.

**Naming**

Some names `shared_ptr.h` names begin with *shared_ptr*, others have *shared_ptr* in the middle.  Recommend uniformity, IMO, begin with *shared_ptr*.

`util.h` is far too generic and gives no hint that it defines `err_exit()`.

`format()` has a high surprising collision potential.

`shared_ptr_t` is a `struct` type, yet contains "ptr".  Better to not call things that are not pointers as `ptr`, etc.

**Surprising exits**

Good to have error *detection*.  `SHARED_PTR_FROM` and others can exit code.    I'd find this too draconian for general use as this code is effectively defining error handle for its use.  Do the *smart pointer* task, yet leave *final error handling* to the application.

**Allocate by object**

Rather that allocate by the type, consider allocating by the referenced object.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// shared_ptr_cntrl_t * cntrl=calloc(1,sizeof(shared_ptr_cntrl_t));
shared_ptr_cntrl_t * cntrl = calloc(1, sizeof * cntrl);
```

**Good use of `#include "util.h"`**

Nice to have `util.c` first include `"util.h"`.  It is a good test of `util.h` sufficiency.

Comment: thanks for the review! regarding `util.h` the included is only a snippet, the actual header contains a few function and macro definitions that don't quite need a separate header of their own, and when extracting the snippet i missed to copy the `#pragma once`

Comment: "may not to wade through" this doesn't read properly to me. Did you by change mean "may not want to wade through"?

Comment: @Zachiah Yes, post updated to your good suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think these can be negative:

> ```
> int64_t count;
> int64_t cntrl_count;
> ```

Consider an unsigned type (perhaps `size_t` is most appropriate?)

This cast and associated use are not portable:

> ```
> create_shared_ptr((void**)&v,(void(*)(void*))cleanup);
> ```

> ```
>           p->cntrl->cleanup(p->cntrl->data);
> ```

Although function pointers can be cast to another function pointer type, calling through such a pointer without casting it back is Undefined Behaviour.  Instead, require that the caller provides a function pointer of that accepts `void*`, as `qsort()` and `bsearch()` do.

> ```
> type * v=calloc(1,sizeof(type));
> shared_ptr_cntrl_t * cntrl=calloc(1,sizeof(shared_ptr_cntrl_t));
> ```

I'd normally write `sizeof *v` and `sizeof *cntrl` respectively.  It's not a big deal here, but is a good practice where the pointer's declaration is far away.

I don't think it's meaningful to copy a pthread mutex like this:

> ```
>             pthread_mutex_t m=p->cntrl->mutex;
>             free(p->cntrl);
>             p->cntrl=NULL;
>             if(pthread_mutex_unlock(&m)){
>                 err_exit("Failed to unlock mutex for shared_ptr");
>             }
>             if(pthread_mutex_destroy(&m)){
>                 err_exit("Failed to destroy mutex for shared_ptr");
>             }
> ```

However, if we're in that code, then we know that there's no other reference in play, so we can simply destroy the mutex we have, before the `free()`:

```
    pthread_mutex_t *const m = &p->cntrl->mutex;

        ...

            if(pthread_mutex_unlock(m)){
                err_exit("Failed to unlock mutex for shared_ptr");
            }
            if(pthread_mutex_destroy(m)){
                err_exit("Failed to destroy mutex for shared_ptr");
            }
            free(p->cntrl);
            p->cntrl=NULL;
```

Comment: Oh, in that case I was wrong.  I believed that function pointers could not be cast to each other.  But I looked it up, and I am now better informed!